# Itunes Connect multiples rejection for an app?

Tags: app-store-connect

If they rejected my app and told me to fix the title, is it the ONLY problem/error i have or after a re-upload my app are they going to give me another error for something else?

Answer (score 0):

They just stopped there. If they find your title is correct then they will proceed with the review.

In case the title was the last step in the review (which I doubt) it could be possible that they accepted your app.

Apple's review process is a black box, but I have experience in solving one issue and then being rejected by another issue.